# jetty, jackson & jersey - insight

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jackson

I recently started developing rest apis and stumbled on these terms - jetty, jackson & jersey.
I successfully developed rest apis using jersey on plain eclipse.

I believe jackson is to facilitate de-serialization and serialization of xml/java objects. But what it is - is it just a collection of jar files? - If yes, can/should I use it alongside if I am already using jersey framework (if my apis deal with xmls)?

Likewise, what ie Jetty - I downloaded it and saw whole lot of folders and files - and they were not just collection of jars! If it is a framework, can I use it on top of jersey?  If yes, it looks pretty heavy - I thought it might just be few jars to deal with html content. But looks like there is lot more to it.

Are these three things meant to be used together if my apis deal with all media types? If yes, how and what is the best approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) is a servlet container.

[Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) is a library that lets you develop restful apis in Java.

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is a java library for JSON processing.

Jetty can be used to "serve" servlets and jsps.  Jersey can be used to build your rest resources but it needs to be run on a servlet container.  Without Jersey you'd be dealing with servlets directly which would be way lower level than you'd want.  And Jackson can be used to serialize your java objects to and from JSON.

Jackson may play more roles than that for Jersey, I'm not sure.  But you can click on the links I've provided to learn more.

Comment: Sometimes, all you need is such a simple explanation!  And I was breaking my head on google trying to figure out what is what.  Thanks a lot! Its clear now.

Comment: Just one more question, does it mean I could Jetty as a container in Spring?

Comment: typically think of it as: Jetty is the servlet container, so it reads the incoming request and passes it off to the jersey servlet that you have registered which if it is json content can use jackson to swizzle it into something you are more comfortable working with.  you can use spring to build out and inject your objects into your jersey setup or you can start up your jetty bits in an embedded fashion with just jetty or via spring as well, we (jetty) support most any strategy you like

Comment: @Tintin Jetty as a container in Spring?  What does that mean?

Comment: @tieTYT I mean right now (I just started with Spring) - I see "VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition v2.9" as a targetted runtime.  Since, it looks to me that Jetty is a container (web server like tomcat?), maybe I could use it a targeted runtime?  please excuse me if I got this completely wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Tintin I understand *some* of what you said.  Yes, you can replace Jetty with Tomcat if you want.  You can also replace it with JBoss or Weblogic or Glassfish, etc.